# List item links not showing( contact, pricing and download)

Tags: bootstrap-4, nav, web-deployment-project

`
Tindog

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

  <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>`
```

This is my code the list items are not showing i dont know why please help me in that.

[They should be showing in the right side in the front of tindog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvpIl.png)

Comment: copy paste [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/), see if it works and then start modifying it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The `collapse` class is by default not showing, If you inspect your `navbar` `div` you will fount out `.collapse:not(.show)` is active, So you should add the `class` `show` to your navbar div like In the example bellow:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Bootstrap4 navbar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="collapse show navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

For better displaying of your `navbar` you can consult the official bootstrap website and see the navbar component page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/